# Large vector causing "Error in sample.int(n, n * R, replace = TRUE) : vector size cannot be NA" but how to fix?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

The boot function doesn't seem to work for 66k resamples. The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/boot/versions/1.3-23/topics/boot) doesn't seem to have any limits for the number of resamples and it works fine with a smaller number of resamples.

Here's some sample code:

```
library(boot)
library(data.table)

mean_i <- function(x, i) {
  mean(x[i])
}

set.seed(1)
x <- data.table(yr = sample(1:5, 66000, replace = TRUE),
                amount = sample(-100000:100000, 66000, replace = TRUE))

boot(x[, amount], statistic = mean_i, R = length(x[, amount]))
```

This gives the error:

> Error in sample.int(n, n * R, replace = TRUE) : vector size cannot be
>   NA

but

```
boot(x[1:100, amount], statistic = mean_i, R = length(x[1:100, amount]))
```

works fine.

Does anyone know if there's a maximum number for resamples or what could be causing the error?

Comment: It looks like `n * R` in your case is 66000*66000, which is an enormously large vector. Do you have enough memory to hold 4.3 billion integers?

Comment: It may be integer overflow. If both `n` and `R` are integers( which is most likely the case), their product is too long to be stored as an integer( See `.Machine$integer.max`) . Plus, as @AdamK mentioned it would be nearly impossible to store a vector of that size in memory.

Comment: A workaround is to do the bootstrap manually: `replicate(length(x[, amount]), {mean(sample(x[, amount], replace = TRUE))})`. This may take minutes to finish.